# How do I Display Code Samples On Web Pages With Nice Syntax Styling Like Stack Overflow Does?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, css

I would like to be able to pull some code samples out of a database and/or have the text embedded into the website and then have the sample formatted in a code like fashion on the screen.  While the text alone on the screen is great, the format will make it more user friendly.  How is this done?

**I want this:**
 public string MyString = "The Sample Text";

---

**To look like:**

```
public string MyString = "The Sample Text";
```

---

**EDIT WITH ANSWER**
I took [Gortok's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749209/display-code-samples-on-web-like-stackoverflow/749229#749229) suggestion and looked into [Prettify.js](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) and its doing just what I had hoped.  Here is how this is implemented.

```
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/prettify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Scripts/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <code class="prettyprint"> 
        public String HelloString = "New String"; 
    </code>  
    <script language="javascript"> 
        $().ready(function() { 
            prettyPrint(); 
        }); 
    </script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Stack Overflow uses [prettify.js](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) from Google.

Answer (score 7):

I use SyntaxHighlighter by Alex Gorbatchev

http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter

It's used on Yahoo Developer Network

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/animation/

Answer (score 4):

would this help:

http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/