# Need to display syntax highlighted source code on my webpage

Tags: php, javascript, css

Currently I'm working on a website where user can post text that can contain source code examples.

A little bit like here on stackoverflow. Where I can type javascript and php and jquery and css and many other languages and they will been syntax higlighted on the page! :)

Like this:

```
<?php echo "Hello friends";?>
```

How do I do it in the best possible way?

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what you are asking here. Can you clarify?

Comment: What I would like to help it to do so that my visitors can see the code I have written a little as I knew in the first :)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand.

Comment: if its php you should have a look at `highlight_file()`

Comment: Try looking here, showing the code on the page: http://www.nemprogrammering.dk/Tutorials/PHP/T4PHP.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Display Code Samples On Web Pages With Nice Syntax Styling Like Stack Overflow Does?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749209/how-do-i-display-code-samples-on-web-pages-with-nice-syntax-styling-like-stack-o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [Highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/); give it a try, it's fairly trivial to [set up and use](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/description/):

> **BASIC USAGE**
>
> Link the library and a stylesheet from your page and hook highlighting
>   to the page load event:
>
> `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/default.css">`
>
> `<script src="highlight.pack.js"></script>`
>   `<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>`
>
> This will highlight all code on the page marked up as `<pre><code> .. </code></pre>`.

Comment: its works!! :D i love this!!!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this project: https://github.com/igorpan/PHPygmentizator

It is a PHP library that uses [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) to highlight a wide range of languages and supports a lot of different styles.

Answer (score 0):

Use php's htmlsafe

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

```
<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a          href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>
```

( off top of my head I can't remember what flag,  but there is a flag that outputs the safe ASCII versions thatrender correctly in browser )
Then use bootstraps code class
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#code